# svg as background-image: xlink to id in original document

Tags: html, svg

We have an icon library that we inline to the bottom of the document, like

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon2" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Those icons are simply referenced wherever we need them, like

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="16px" height="16px">
  <use xlink:href="#icon1"/>
</svg>
```

Now sometimes we need to use the icons as a background-image, similar to

```html
<div style="width:16px; height:16px; background-size:cover; background-image: url(//placehold.it/16x16)"></div>
```

It is possible to use svgs as background images using `data:image/svg+xml` data URIs as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/):

```html
<div style='width:16px; height:16px; background-size:cover; background-image:url(&apos;data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/></svg>&apos;)'></div>
```

However, referencing IDs from inside the data URI does not work in the same way:

```html
<h3>referenced in <code>svg</code></h3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="16px" height="16px">
  <use xlink:href="#icon"/>
</svg>

<h3>referenced in <code>background-image</code>
<div style="width:16px; height:16px; background-size:cover; background-image:url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><use xlink:href='#icon'/></svg>&quot;)"></div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I assume the `data:image/svg+xml` creates a new "context" for the document, so `#icon` refers to a node inside the `data:image/svg+xml` (which is not there, because it is in the original document).

*Is there a way to reference the original document (like with something similar to [`ShadowRoot.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/host) from the Shadow DOM API)?* (maybe something like `xlink:href=":host#icon"`)

The only workaround that would come to my mind is to use JavaScript to inline the used symbol:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[style*="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,"]'))
  .forEach(function(e) {    
    e.style.backgroundImage = getComputedStyle(e).backgroundImage.replace(
      /<use xlink:href='#([^']+)'\/>/g,
      function(match, id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.replace(/(^\s*|\s*$)/g, '').replace(/"/g, "'")
      }
    )
  })
```

```html
<h3>referenced in <code>background-image</code> with JS inlining</h3>
<div style="width: 16px; height: 16px; background-size: cover; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><use xlink:href='#icon'/></svg>&quot;)"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

But I would really hope to avoid JavaScript at all.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jennhi/post/using-svg-symbols-as-css-backgrounds shows how to do it using anchors that refer to specific elements in a fully external SVG; but I don’t think the combination of inline svg and completely different background SVG elsewhere will work.

Comment: It'll take me some time to work through the details of the article, but that looks like a possible alternative (and it works even in IE11, which is a necessary requirement for us). Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a subtle variation on a common question.

> Is there a way to reference the original document

The answer is **no**.  Any file (and this includes those in the form of a Data URL) loaded as an `<img>` or `background-image` etc, need to be self contained.  They are loaded as a stand-alone object, and cannot reference other files.

You would need to include the `<symbol>` in your Data URL.

Comment: Hi Paul, shouldn't this work if the symbol referenced is defined in the same SVG? I'm trying to get a somewhat complicated SVG working as a background data URI, but the entire thing fails if there's a `<use xlink:href="...` in it, even though it's linking to an element defined within that same URI. What's confusing to me, is this works perfectly fine with masks (ie. `mask="url(#maskdef)"` where the mask was defined within the same URI), so shouldn't the use element work too? https://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/oOBamx

Comment: @Chase Your SVG is faulty. (1) It uses the xlink namespace, so it needs to define that namespace. (2) "#" is a special character in URLs. So it needs to be escaped (ie. %23). https://jsfiddle.net/e5rhgbv9/